# Sorting ArrayList<CustomObject>

Tags: java, sorting, collections, arraylist

I'm facing problem while trying to sort an ArrayList of custom object. In fact, after the sorting, nothing has change in my ArrayList. Is something wrong with my method?

Here's my Artist custom object property :

```
public class Artist {

String mNickname;
String mName;
String mDescription;
String mScene;
String mDay;
String mTime;
String mImageURL;   
Date mDate;

// getters and setters below like getDate() for mDate...
```

And here's the method use to sort :

```
static public ArrayList<Artist> sortArrayByDate(ArrayList<Artist> list) {       

    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Artist>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Artist lhs, Artist rhs) {
            if (lhs.getDate().getTime() < rhs.getDate().getTime())
                return -1;
            else if (lhs.getDate().getTime() == rhs.getDate().getTime())
                return 0;
            else
                return 1;
        }
    });

    return list;
}
```

I know this topic as been discuss many time on StackOverflow, but I can't find why I'm not able to make it work properly. Thanks for your understanding

EDIT : Dates (java.util.date) are create using SimpleDateFormatter

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", Locale.CANADA_FRENCH);
```

Comment: could you tell me what kind of date format you used?

Comment: I construct my date using :

   SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", Locale.CANADA_FRENCH);

Comment: can you post it up in your code? so i can post my answer too :)

Comment: thank you. so you just use Date class and parse it with this format?

Comment: I have diffuclty to come up with a format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not simply use [Date#compareTo()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo%28java.util.Date%29) for the comparison since `java.util.Date` implements the `Comparable` interface.

It is not necessary for the method to return an instance of the `List` after it is sorted because the underlying `List` object will be modified by invoking sort.  Basically, the method is invoked by passing a reference value as an argument. So when modifications are made, the changes are reflected on the underlying object pointed to by the reference value.  With this approach, the code simply passes the `List` into the method and then continues using the same reference in the proceeding code, which will point to an underlying `List` which has been sorted.

Another item to consider is modifying the method to accept an argument of the type `List`as opposed to `ArrayList`, since `List` is an interface, hence more abstract.  This would allow the code to switch the implementation of `List` being passed to the method. This is important because `ArrayList` does not guarantee the order of the items in the list is maintained.  To guarantee the order of items in the `List` is maintained used `LinkedList`.

```
static public void sortArrayByDate(List<Artist> list) {       

    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Artist>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Artist lhs, Artist rhs) {
            return lhs.getDate().compareTo(rhs.getDate());
        }
    });

}
```

Here is a [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/kmb385/216bb1adbdf8f96b983b) I created, that show this method in action, with a complete working example.

Comment: @KickButtowski I'm assuming `java.util.Date`

Comment: just for my learning goal, how your answer will help his issue when he uses this format? SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", Locale.CANADA_FRENCH);

Comment: It shouldn't matter how he constructs the `Date` once the `Date` is constructed its a `Date` and it can be compared using its `compareTo` method.

Comment: I know that but he wants getTime comparison not date?

Comment: @KickButtowski getTime returns the date representation of millis since Unix epoch, which is what Date.compareTo does under the covers. You can verify by checking out the Java source. Hooking this into Eclipse is very useful so you can see how anything in the java or javax packages are implemented

Comment: @LINEMAN78 so could you just give me a object of Artist? like Artist a = new Artist(); something like that

Comment: @KickButtowski I'm confused what you are asking... You could make Artist implement comparable like java.util.Date does, but I believe this should only be used when it is obvious, which in this case I don't think it is. How would you know that calling sort on a collection of Artists will sort by date and not name; however java.util.Date is another story as it is obvious that it represents a single value. getTime simply represents the Date in milliseconds since Jan 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC. Comparing anything other than this can cause issues with leap seconds.

Comment: @LINEMAN78 may be I am too tired I try to use lambda but it seems I should solve this later cuz my brain is shout down :)

Comment: @Boris88 Glad I could help.  There are plenty of great posts out there that explain pass by value in better terms.  I would recommend this article: http://www.javaranch.com/campfire/StoryPassBy.jsp .  It is pretty important to understand this underlying concept in Java.